# Extending MVC RadioButtonFor using HtmlHelper extensions

Tags: model-view-controller, custom-controls

I'm trying to build an HtmlHelper to add functionality to an MVC RadioButtonFor control. I simply want to add a class and style attribute to the radio button given certain conditions. I can't seem to get my extension to include attributes. I've followed several examples I've found online, but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GCSRadioButtonForHelper<TModel>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> expression,
        Object htmlAttributes,
        object value            )
    {

        bool isRequired = false;
        bool isHidden = false;
        object styleList;
        object classList;

        Dictionary<string, object> attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        attributes.TryGetValue("class", out classList);
        attributes.TryGetValue("style", out styleList);

        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        var categoryName = string.Empty;
        if (metadata.ContainerType != null)
            categoryName = metadata.ContainerType.Name + "." + metadata.PropertyName;

        isHidden = GetIsHidden(metadata);
        isRequired = GetIsRequired(metadata);

        if (isHidden)
            classList = classList + " GCSHidden ";

        if (isRequired)
        {
            classList = classList + " GCSRequired ";
        }

        attributes.Remove("class");
        attributes.Remove("style");

        attributes.Add("class", classList);
        attributes.Add("style", styleList);

        //Render HTML String
        MvcHtmlString html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor(htmlHelper, expression, attributes, value);
        return html;

    }
```

The problem is that the result of InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor() never includes the attributes class or style as I have specified. Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: You're calling the extension you've created from inside the extension.  You are aware of this?

Comment: TheGeekYouNeed, I'm not following. I'm explicitly invoking the InputExtensions.RadioButtomFor() method. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: actually read your code wrong at the top -- let me answer you in the answer area

Comment: For a start your specifying the wrong order of the parameters - its `InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor(htmlHelper, expression, value, attributes);` but there are other errors and pointless code in your method as well. What are you actually trying to do with this, and what are your methods `GetIsHidden()` and `GetIsRequired()`?

Comment: Stephen Muecke, thanks for identifying the issue. Sometimes, too many hours in front of the computer do that. The other code is not relevant to my question, I should have removed it.  Thanks again.